# Can we relate these four determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant, cross-product

\begin{equation}
D_1 
=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 &1& \beta_2\\
\alpha_2 &1& \beta_3\\
\alpha_3 &1& \beta_1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D_2 = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 &1& \alpha_2\\
\beta_2 &1& \alpha_3\\
\beta_3 &1& \alpha_1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D_3 = 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_3 & \beta_2\\
\alpha_2 & \alpha_1 & \beta_3\\
\alpha_3 & \alpha_2 & \beta_1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D_4 = 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_3 & \beta_2\\
\alpha_2 & \beta_1 & \beta_3\\
\alpha_3 & \beta_2 & \beta_1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

Note that $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ are real numbers.

Can we relate and connect the four determinants $D_i$, for $i=1,2,3,4$? Can we point out some relations between them?

For example:
If $D_1=D_2=0$, then it implies that $D_3=0$ or $D_4=0$.[this property is already known] I am searching for other connections and relationship between D_i.

Something like this but not limited to
$D_1 = 0, D_2 \neq 0$, $D_2 \neq 0, D_1 =0$, $D_1 >0, D_2 = 0$ what happens to $D_3, D_4$?

Any interesting properties connecting the four determinants are welcome!

EDIT

Mainly,if we fix $D_1<0$ and  $D_2<0$ then what happens to
$D_3, D_4$ ? How they behave?

The question has arised from a question on MathOverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426170/is-it-impossible-for-determinants-of-these-matrices-to-both-be-negative

Comment: Nice, it would be interesting to see those relations actually!

Comment: Why is this of interest?

Comment: Please see edited question

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if $D_1=D_2=0$, then either $D_3=0$ or $D_4=0$.

To see this, consider two cases.

*Case 1:* $\alpha_3=\alpha_1$. Then $D_1=0$ says $(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)(\beta_1-\beta_2)=0$. If $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$, then $D_3=0$. If $\beta_1=\beta_2$, then $D_2=0$ implies $D_3=0$ or $D_4=0$.

*Case 2:* $\alpha_3-\alpha_1\neq 0$. Then $D_1=0$ says
$$
\beta_3:= -\frac{1}{\alpha_3- \alpha_1}(\alpha_1\beta_1 - \alpha_2\beta_1 + \alpha_2\beta_2 - \alpha_3\beta_2)
$$

Eliminating $\beta_2$ from $D_2=0$ we obtain $D_4=0$.

**Edit**: Here is a new one. If $D_1=D_2=D_3=1$, or if
$D_1=D_2=D_3=-1$,
then $D_4=0$ if and only if
$$
\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=2.
$$

Comment: Thanks! but this property is already known] I am searching for other connections and relationship between D_i

Comment: OK, then here is a new one. If $D_1=0$, $D_2=D_3=1$, then $D_4\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, please see. the edited answer.

Comment: Your question "if we fix $D_1<0,D_2<0$,  then what happens to $D_3,D_4$ " is too vague. Can you be more precise? For example, saying $D_1=D_2=-1$ has a lot of consequences for the relation of $D_3$ and $D_4$. But which consequences do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Define two more determinants
\begin{equation}
D_5 := 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_3 & \beta_1\\
\alpha_2 & \alpha_1 & \beta_2\\
\alpha_3 & \alpha_2 & \beta_3
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D_6 := 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_3 & \beta_3 & \beta_2\\
\alpha_1 & \beta_1 & \beta_3\\
\alpha_2 & \beta_2 & \beta_1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Define two more values
$$ A := \alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2
 - \alpha_1\alpha_2 - \alpha_1\alpha_3 - \alpha_2\alpha_3, \\
 B := \beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2 + \beta_3^2
    - \beta_1\beta_2 - \beta_1\beta_3 - \beta_2\beta_3. $$
Verify that
$$ B\,D_3 = D_1D_6 + D_2D_4, \quad
D_3 = D_1\alpha_1 + D_2\alpha_2 + \beta_3A = \\
D_1\alpha_2 + D_2\alpha_3 + \beta_1A =
D_1\alpha_3 + D_2\alpha_1 + \beta_2A. $$
Suppose that $\,D_1 = D_2 = 0.\,$ The first case is
if $\,\beta_1 = \beta_2 = \beta_3 = 0,\,$ then $\,D_3 = 0.\,$
Second case is if $\,A = 0\,$ then $\,D_3 = 0.\,$
Third case is if $\,A \ne 0.\,$
Verify that
$\, A B = D_1^2 - D_1D_2 + D_2^2 \,$ which implies that $\,B=0\,$
but the identity with $\,D_6\,$ implies that $\,D_3 = 0\,$ again.

Thus, in all three cases, $\,D_1 = D_2 = 0\,$ implies that $\,D_3 = 0.\,$

Similar identities hold for $\,D_4 = 0.\,$ Thus, if
$\,D_1 = D_2 = 0\,$ then $\,D_3 = 0\,$ or $\,D_4 = 0.\,$

Comment: I have a counterexample. Let $\alpha_1=1,\alpha_2=2,\alpha_3=3$ and $\beta_i=1$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then $D_1=D_2=D_4=0$, but $D_3=3$. But one of $D_3$ and $D_4$ has to be zero.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for that comment! I will have to fix my logic.

Comment: You still say "In all cases, $D_1=D_2=0$ implies that $D_3=0$". But this is not true, right?

Comment: @BAYMAX Yes, but I have other relations. For example, $BD_3=D_1D_6 +D_2D_4.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Thanks, please see. the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-You can get many relations depending upon the numerical values of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$. For example, noting that
$$\begin{equation}
D_2 =(-1)(-1)(-1) \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 &1& \beta_3\\
\alpha_2 &1& \beta_1\\
\alpha_3 &1& \beta_1
\end{pmatrix}=-\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 &1& \beta_3\\
\alpha_2 &1& \beta_1\\
\alpha_3 &1& \beta_1
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}$$ and developping with the first row, you have  $$D_1-D_2+D_3+D_4=\alpha_1X+\alpha_2Y+\alpha_3Z=N$$ where $X=\beta_1-\beta_2+\beta_2-\beta_1+\beta_3-\beta_2=\beta_3-\beta_2$, etc.

All being function of reals involved. However maybe there are relations (like what happen with $X$) of interest with just the literal values.

Comment: Thanks, please see. the edited answer.